# list of list multiplication with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply a list of list with a list using python 3 suppose that the list of list is of name `L` as follows:

```
L = [[45.909221207388235, 84.41069326628269], [80.6591435966521, 47.93257841035172]]
```

and the second list is:

```
S = [0.002, 0.001]
```

the multiplication should be: `L[0][0]* S[0]` and `L[0][1]* S[0]` then `L[1][0]* S[1]` and `L[1][1]* S[1]`.

I tried the `zip` method :

```
[a*b for x,y in zip(S,L) for a,b in zip(x,y)]
```

But an error appears: `zip` argument `1` must support iteration.

the second trial was using `map(lambda)`:

```
map(lambda x,y:x*y,L,S)
```

but the obtained results were wrong:

```
[9.181844241477647e-05, 0.00016882138653256538, 0.0001613182871933042, 9.586515682070343e-05]
```

the correct values are:

```
[0.09181844241477648, 0.1688213865325654, 0.0806591435966521, 0.047932578410351714]
```

Comment: You can do this using numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `zip`, but not twice:

```
>>> L = [[45.909221207388235, 84.41069326628269], [80.6591435966521, 47.93257841035172]]
>>> S = [0.002, 0.001]
>>> [n*x for n, sub in zip(S, L) for x in sub]
[0.09181844241477648, 0.1688213865325654, 0.0806591435966521, 0.047932578410351714]
>>>
```

So, you want to pair up every number with every sublist, then multiply every number in the sublist by that main number.

Note, just in case you *are* using `numpy` (I don't think you are, and I don't think it would be reasonable to use `numpy` just for this), and `S` and `L` are `numpy.ndarray` objects, i.e.:

```
>>> S = np.array(S)
>>> L = np.array(L)
```

Then you probably just want:

```
>>> (S*L).ravel()
array([0.09181844, 0.08441069, 0.16131829, 0.04793258])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corresly you want to multiply each column in L by the corresponding value of S:

```
L = [[45.909221207388235, 84.41069326628269],
     [80.6591435966521, 47.93257841035172]]
S = [0.002, 0.001]

R = [ [s*n for n in row] for s,row in zip(S,L) ]
```

output:

```
print(R)
[ [0.09181844241477648, 0.1688213865325654],
  [0.0806591435966521,  0.047932578410351714]]
```

*You should have given an example with a different number of rows than columns to make this clearer*